# Spark joinWithCassandraTable() on map multiple partition key ERROR

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying to filter on a small part of a huge Cassandra table by using:

```
val snapshotsFiltered = sc.parallelize(startDate to endDate).map(TableKey(_2)).joinWithCassandraTable("listener","snapshots_test_b")
```

I want to map the rows in the cassandra table on 'created' column that is part of the partition key.

My table key (the partition key of the table) defined as:

```
case class TableKey(imei: String, created: Long, when: Long)
```

The result is an error:

> [error] /home/ubuntu/scala/test/test.scala:61: not enough arguments for method apply: (imei: String, created: Long)test.TableKey in object TableKey.
>   [error] Unspecified value parameter created.
>   [error]         val snapshotsFiltered = sc.parallelize(startDate to endDate).map(TableKey(_2)).joinWithCassandraTable("listener","snapshots_test_b")
>   [error]                                                                                  ^
>   [error] one error found
>   [error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed

It worked with only one object in the partition key as in the [Documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md).

Why there is a problem with multiple partition key?- answered.

EDIT: I tried to use the joinWithCassandraTable in the right form:

```
val snapshotsFiltered = sc.parallelize(startDate to endDate).map(TableKey("*",_,startDate)).joinWithCassandraTable("listener","snapshots_test_c")
```

When I trying to run it on Spark there is no errors but it stuck on "[stage 0:> (0+2)/2]" forever...

What goes wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that the class `TableKey` requires 3 components to initialize yet there was only a single argument passed. This is a Scala compilation error and isn't related to C* or Spark.

```
 val snapshotsFiltered = sc.parallelize(startDate to endDate)
   .map(TableKey(_2))  /// Table Key does not have a single element constructor so this will fail
   .joinWithCassandraTable("listener","snapshots_test_b")
```

---

In general though, C* uses the entire `partition key` do determine where a particular row lives. Because of this you can only efficiently pull out data if you know the entire `partition key` so passing only a portion of it has no value.

The joinWithCassandraTable requires full `partition key` values so it can effeciently do it's work. if you only have a portion of the `parition key` you will be required to perform a full table scan and use Spark to filter.

If you only want to filter based on a `clustering column` you can do so by pushing down a `where` clause to C* such as

```
sc.cassandraTable("ks","test").where("clustering_key > someValue")
```